# How to write closure used in swift to objective c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

[UIAlertController 'UIAlertAction' tag/userdata or anything in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286395/uialertcontroller-uialertaction-tag-userdata-or-anything-in-swift)

Based on this solution for handling click action for dynamic created UIAlertController.

I was searching for objective c code to convert closure to block.

```
let closure = { (index: Int) in
     { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
         println("Index: \(index)")
     }
 }
```

Comment: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/ ??

Comment: @GoodSp33d thank you i was able to convert to Objective C using your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do using below Objective C blocks

```
  void (^closure)(UIAlertAction *) = ^(UIAlertAction *action){
        NSInteger index = [alertcontroller.actions indexOfObject:action];
        NSLog(@"Button Index%ld", (long)index);
    };
```